# javascript password checker with confirmation dont work

Tags: javascript, passwords

Could anyone help me i have following issue with it when i put the wrong passwort it still gives no alert and opens the site.(the whole code isnt working and i dont know where the error is..) thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> passwort </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function vergleiche(a, b) {
            return (a == b) ? true : false;
        }

        function val(frm) {
            if (vergleiche("passwort", frm.password.value){
                alert("pw richtig");
            }
            else {
                alert("pw falsch");
                frm.password.select();
                frm.password.focus;
            }

            if (frm.password.value == "") {
                alert("enter password abla");
                frm.password.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if ((frm.password.value).length < 3) {
                alert("dein pw sollte schon länger sein hö");
                frm.password.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (frm.confirmpassword.value == "") {
                alert("enter password");
                return false;
            }
            if (frm.password.value != frm.confirmpassword.value) {
                alert("passwoerter ungleich lan");
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<h2> passwort validation</h2>
<form name="frm" method="POST" action="pw.php" onSubmit="">
    Enter vorname:<input type="text" name="vorname"/>
    Enter Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/><br/>
    <br/>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Re-enter Password"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick=""/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: At the very least properly indent your code.

Comment: You are **NOT** even calling your function `val()`.

Comment: You should do a read up on form validation .http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Answer (score 0):

1. As Rax Weber said, you are not even calling your function.
2. You should not pass your form this way.

I think it's better to do something like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="val()" />
```

And in val function. (Because your form don't have an ID....)

```
frm = document.getElementsByName("frm")[0];
```

3. The line "if(vergleiche("passwort",frm.password.value) {" is incorrect, you are missing one ")"

   if(vergleiche("passwort",frm.password.value)) {

Proceeding like this, your function should work. However, I would recommand that you translate your code in english so everyone can understand, and you should also use some IDE like Eclipse or at least Notepad++ to indent your code properly.

Using those tools will make you do less syntax errors.

Comment: Np, if that helped, you can mark my answer.  :P

BTW, with Notepad, you should install IndentByFold plugin which can be found here https://code.google.com/archive/p/indentbyfold/downloads or by the Plugin Manager